# How can I manually partition and provision a Windows 8 USB install drive with UEFI bios and GPT scheme?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, uefi, gpt

For whatever reason, I cannot get the windows 7 and windows 8 usb install tools to see my usbdrive, even though my bios can. How can I manually (from elevated command prompt) partition and provision windows 8 installer given an install media iso file?

What I have tried already:

- Windows 7/8 usb install tools from windows store - usb drive is not seen
- Rufus - drive is seen with "show usb drive settings", successfully boots and installs win8 after changing bios to "enable legacy support". System will not boot after legacy support is disabled again.
- Tried diskpart - failed to boot
- Tried drive on another system, works fine bu still not seen by win 7 install tool

Comment: MS's DVD download tool? http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Never sees the usb drive.

Comment: Does it show up in Windows' Disk Management? Does it have a partition on it?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to waste your time, I have tried a number of solutions and have concluded that I need to do it from the commandline.

Comment: Yes what?  Have you tried DISKPART?  Have you tried the USB drive in another computer ot confirm it actually works?  To the point of not wasting time -- please edit your question to include what you've already tried and what the results were.   So we don't waste time asking you if you've done stuff you've already done.

Comment: Sorry, updated with info you've requested. Thanks again.

Comment: None of what you edited in answers any of my questions. :/  Anyhow, I'm off for now, good luck!

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you used the Win7 instructions for Win8?

Comment: Sorry, win7 instructions? I tried both the win7 and win8 dvd download tools. I'm not sure if that's what you mean. Most sources I saw said that the win7 usb download tool is compaptible with win8 media iso

Comment: Rufus is probably your best bet - you have to make sure to pick GPT, and pick the option to make it bootable . . .